# Kendo-ui datagrid mousedown is not detecte by IE8

Tags: datagrid, kendo-ui, mousedown

This worked perfect with Chrome, but IE8 is not firing this action. I tried the code below. I see the message in chrome, but IE8 is not displaying it that makes me think it is not recognizing this method:

```
$('#datasheetGrid').data('kendoGrid').tbody.on('mousedown',function(e){
     if(e.altKey || event.button == 2){
         alert('');
     }
});
```

Comment: Which version of Kendo UI are you using? Did you try it with IE9?

Answer (score 1):

Attach the event to the underlying element instead.

```
$('#datasheetGrid').data('kendoGrid').element.on('mousedown',function(e) {
     if (e.altKey || e.button == 2){
         alert('Clicked!');
     }
});
```